# Mavericks Webdav authentication - Unable to lookup user record

Tags: macos, apache, webdav, osx-server

I want to configure webdav service from mavericks mac os x server.
I edited http-dav.conf as below;

```
DavLockDB "/usr/davlock""
```

Alias /uploads "/usr/uploads"

Dav On

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all

AuthType Digest
AuthName DAV-upload

# You can use the htdigest program to create the password database:
#   htdigest -c "/usr/user.passwd" DAV-upload admin
AuthUserFile "/usr/user.passwd"
AuthDigestProvider file

# Allow universal read-access, but writes are restricted
# to the admin user.
<LimitExcept GET OPTIONS>
    require user admin
</LimitExcept>
```

after that ; 
I created /usr/uploads and /usr/davlock directories.
and I run;

```
chown -R www:www /usr/uploads
chown -R www:www /usr/davlock
chown -R www:www /usr/usr.passwd
htdigest -c "/usr/user.passwd" DAV-upload admin
```

commands.
and I type server address format as `"http://192.168.1.20/uploads"`
and system ask me credential information.
I insert credential information and not accept.
When I read apache log files, I see below lines;

```
[Sat Oct 26 08:54:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.20] mod_digest_apple: Unable to lookup user record
[Sat Oct 26 08:54:55 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.20] mod_digest_apple: Unable to find user "admin" in directory
```

Am I missing something? Should this work?